3 Phase Pulse Generator
I cobbled together a simple 3 phase pulse generator for a project I am working on. I've attached a picture of the circuit. I need to get a quick (~50ns) pulse on each phase.
I have concerns about the constant width pulse generation part made out of cascading inverters.
At high input clock rates (30Mhz in, 10Mhz per phase) would the inverters rapidly switching cause issues in a real world circuit? Is there a better way to get a short, constant width pulse? (i.e. noise, logic glitches, etc?)
I'm looking to use 74LS logic for the implementation if that matters. The inverters have around ~10ns propagation delay.


Are you trying to create a pulse of about 50ns duration on both the rising and falling edges from one digital signal?  What if the duration of that signal is shorter than the 50ns pulse width, what do you want to happen in that case?  Are you using this to try to create a "deadtime" to control the on/off of the two switches in one arm (pole) of a power converter?

I just need a sequence of 3 phases, 120 degrees apart, with 50ns pulse width on each channel.

Questions: Q1. Are these pulses on three separate lines (nodes), or are all three pulses on the same line (node)?  Q2.  What is the time between these 50ns pulses?  Q3.  What is the signal providing the edge that each of these pulses is triggered from?


Separate 2. The repetition rate max is 5Mhz per line. So about 150ns between falling edge to the next rising edge. 3. The source is a function generator outputting a square wave at 50% duty cycle into a 50 ohm termination right before the 'clock' input. Hope this helps


Q4.   Do any part of the 50ns pulses on each line ever overlap in time?  ie: can the 50ns exist on the one node and be distributed to each of the 3 lines, or are 3 separate 50ns nodes required?  Q5.  How much variation in the 50ns is permitted between each line?

The 50ns pulses cannot overlap. The pulses can be under 50ns, but cannot be long enough that they overlap.

I think the use of discrete 74LS logic is wrong for this kind of task.
First, you would need to "align" the control signals from your encoder, since currently all edges will be all over the place due to differences in propagation time across FF and logic gates. So you need to put some synchronous latch between your 3-phase generator and output buffers.
Then, all pulses will likely drift with temperature changes.
One right way to get accurate pulses is to use FPGA or CPLD. I would recommend a variant I am familiar with, which is to use XILINX/AMD cheap CPLD like XC9536XL or CoolRunner series, there are evaluation boards for under $15.
To get the project done, you will need to install their free ISE development studio, learn a bit of Verilog, create Finite State Machine for your pulses, and run simulations with post-routing (the simulator is included in the studio). You can assert IO timing constraints on your signals, so the synthesis/configuration software will align internal routing to your requirement. This is the contemporary way to do digital logic, and it might look good on your resume.

This sounds like a good idea, however this would be my first fpga project and I am unfamiliar with them. Can I guarantee my pulse timings with a design check in the software?

@Brian, I am not sure about old CPLDs, but the other old FPGA as Spartan-6 can have 500MHz internal clock, I/O pads do have latches, and the timing of IO buffers can be tuned to 1/256 of the I/O clock.  There will be some learning curve, but believe me, it is worth to master this extremely flexible modern technology. If I recall correctly, the design input even can be done in the form of "schematics capture" from TTL-like basic logic elements, just as in the diagram you posted, and several more methods do exist.

There are some TTL chips called monostable multivibrators that might do what you need.  Look up 74LS123.

I have used these before and will look into them more.
